# Using for loop and mutate to create variables

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a dataset that has a column for the type and a column for the amount. I'm trying to clean the data so that it is one column for each possible type with the amount as the value in that column.

My data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  type_1 = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "AA", "BB"),
  type_2 = c("BB", "CC", "AA", "BB", "CC"),
  val_1 = c(4, 3, 2, 1, 4),
  val_2 = c(5, 6, 7, 2, 1)
)
```

Ideally it would look like this:

```
ideal <- data.frame(
  type_1 = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "AA", "BB"),
  type_2 = c("BB", "CC", "AA", "BB", "CC"),
  val_1 = c(4, 3, 2, 1, 4),
  val_2 = c(5, 6, 7, 2, 1),
  val_AA = c(4, NA, 7, 1, NA),
  val_BB = c(5, 3, NA, 2, 4), 
  val_CC = c(NA, 6, 7, NA, 1)
)
```

My real dataset is much bigger than this, so I am trying to write a for loop to iterate the process of creating the "val_AA", etc. variables.

So far I've created the names vector and attempted this for loop, but am getting errors:

```
names <- c("AA", "BB", "CC")

for(i in names){
  new <- df %>% 
    mutate(paste0("val_",i) = 
             case_when(type_1 == i ~ val_1,
                       type_2 == i ~ val_2,
                       .default = NA)
    )
}
```

I don't fully understand for loops, so any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

(I suspect you have a typo in your third row of `ideal`, and that the `val_CC` column should have a 2 there?)

```
library(tidyr); library(dplyr)  
df <- df %>% mutate(row = row_number())
left_join(
  df,
  df %>%
    pivot_longer(-row, names_to = c(".value", "set"), names_sep = "_") %>%
    select(-set) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = type, names_prefix = "val_",values_from = val)
)
```

Result

```
Joining with `by = join_by(row)`
  type_1 type_2 val_1 val_2 row val_AA val_BB val_CC
1     AA     BB     4     5   1      4      5     NA
2     BB     CC     3     6   2     NA      3      6
3     CC     AA     2     7   3      7     NA      2
4     AA     BB     1     2   4      1      2     NA
5     BB     CC     4     1   5     NA      4      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively with `cur_column`

```r
df1 <- df %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(type_2, val_2), names_from = c(type_1), values_from = c(val_1)) %>% 
  mutate(across(c('AA','BB','CC'), ~ ifelse(cur_column()==type_2,val_2,.x))) %>% 
  select(c('AA','BB','CC')) %>% 
  setNames(paste0('val_',c('AA','BB','CC')))


df2 <- cbind(df,df1)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
  type_1 type_2 val_1 val_2 val_AA val_BB val_CC
1     AA     BB     4     5      4      5     NA
2     BB     CC     3     6     NA      3      6
3     CC     AA     2     7      7     NA      2
4     AA     BB     1     2      1      2     NA
5     BB     CC     4     1     NA      4      1
```